# modify firebug dom object with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom, firebug

[image: Firebug Screenshot showing an object tree.]

The screenshot of Firebug above shows the DOM objects from a site I have loaded. Actually I am using a library (EditableGrid) to allow me editing a table called 'itemlist'.

I want to set the `columns` property `editable` to `false` "on the fly" with JavaScript.
In the header bar of Firebug I see *Window* > *databgrid* > *editableGrid* > *columns* > *3*.

Can anybody point me to the correct way on accessing and modifing the "editable" object attribute of column 3.

I tried in various combinations of

```js
var tbl = document.getElementById('itemlist');

var col = document.getElementClassName('window.datagrid.editableGrid.columns');
col.value = "true";
```

but I couldn't access the property.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` and `document.getElementClassName()` select HTML elements. You want to access a DOM object. Looking at the path shown within Firebug's *DOM* panel it should be accessible directly via `datagrid.editableGrid.columns[3]`.

Comment: when I enter the statement in the console window: var eg3 = document.getElementsByName('datagrid.editableGrid.columns[3]') I get a reply undefined. That is still my problem.

Comment: Don't use `document.getElementsByName()` or suchlike, just enter `datagrid.editableGrid.columns[3]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian was perfectly right. There is no need to retrieve the element via the DOM functions.

```
value = datagrid.editableGrid.columns[3];
```

Just retrieves the datastructure variable. I wasn't aware that black/bold colored objects could be set and get directly.